# Matplotlib x-axis label re-positioning

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to move the x-axis label "number of patients" right below the x-tick value '0'?

[image]

The code I used to create the bar chart is as follows:

```
n_counts.plot.barh(stacked=True, width=0.7, figsize=(12,8), color=['navy','cornflowerblue']);

plt.draw()

# Get current tick positions and labels
pos, lab = plt.xticks()

# Edit labels
new_label = [int(x)*-1 if int(x)<0 else int(x) for x in pos]

# Set new labels
plt.xticks(pos, new_label)
plt.ylabel('neighbourhood', fontsize=13)
plt.xlabel('number of patients', fontsize=13)
plt.legend(['attended', 'not attended'], title='Attendance')
plt.title('            Attendance Counts in Top 20 Regions', loc='left', fontsize=16);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to transform the data coordinate of the x-label (`0` in the example) to axes coordinates to place the label:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlim((-2, 10))
x = 0  # position of xlabel

ax.set_xlabel("xlabel", ha='left', x=ax.transAxes.inverted().transform(ax.transData.transform((x, 0)))[0])
```

[image]

`transData` transforms data coordinates into display coordinates that are then transformed back into Axes coordinates using the inverse `transAxes` Axes transformation. See the [Transformations Tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) for further details.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to shift the x-axis label, you can use `set_label_coords()` to do this. Below is a stripped down version of your plot with the adjusted position.

The position of (0,0) is the bottom left corner of the box. As the x-axis ticks go from 0 to 9, with the 0-value tick at the second position from left corner, I used 2/9 = 0.22 as the x-coordinate. This will allow you to keep the text below the second tick. For y-coordinate, -0.05 suits this figure size and you can adjust it to a larger or smaller number based on the plot getting smaller or bigger respectively. You can fine tune it to suit your requirement...

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
ax.set_xlim(-2000, 7000)
start, end = ax.get_xlim()
# Edit labels
labels = [-2000,-1000,0,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000]
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(start, end+1, 1000))
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)

# Set new labels
ax.set_ylabel('neighbourhood', fontsize=13)
ax.set_xlabel('number of patients', fontsize=13)
ax.legend(['attended', 'not attended'], title='Attendance')
ax.set_title('Attendance Counts in Top 20 Regions', loc='left', fontsize=16);
ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(.22, -0.05)
```

[image]

Comment: Just a nitpick: you might want to get rid of all the `plt` stuff and use the object-orientated approach when it's possible.

Comment: you didn't tell us how you arrived at `.22` for the x coordinate of the label (other than by trial and error)

Comment: You are right @Stef, missed it - added it now

Comment: Thanks @Guimoute - almost all the `plt` part is from the original code, didn't want to mess with that, as it would be easier to use/reuse. Just created new ticks and ticklabels... any specific improvements, do let me know, will incorporate

Comment: @Redox I have added suggestions via an edit.